# in wordpress theme my lost password link is wrong how to change that link?

Tags: php, wordpress

/my-account__trashed/lost-password/ ,my-account__trashed this is wrong tag how to correct it.I tried everything but not get how to change if anyone know please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not seem to be with your theme. This is due to the fact your my-account Page has been sent to Trash from WP Dashboard. All you need to do is, go to WP Dashboard > Pages then find the trash and restore my-account page.

Comment: Yes i had done this before but then restored my account page. I dont understand what should i do :(

Comment: FYI: The problem was solved when I disabled “likes” and “share” on the page in question. Awkwardly enough – but I’m glad it was an easy fix! Now you know too, in case someone else has the same issue<-----i got this solution but the problem is where can i disable that like and share ??